# why does the screensaver show my desktop before locking?

Tags: 11.10, screensaver

I leave my PC on for a while... and then the screensaver kicks in. Cool. So after another while I move my mouse or strike a key or whatever.

This shows me the complete desktop, with like all the apps open. THEN, after like 2 seconds or more it starts fading out the desktop and THEN I get the "gimme the password" prompt.

why does this happen?

edit: it's been a while and I applied all the upgrades in the meantime and this keeps getting worse and worse. Left the machine unattended for a while with VMPlayer 4.02 running with WinXP as guest OS. Came back to the machine, both monitors are in standby, so far so good. Moved my mouse and both monitors came on. No password prompt, no nothing. I interacted with the VM for like two minutes and the shut the VM down. Then, the screens started fading to black and THEN the password prompt came up.

Comment: Hey Jacob, thanks for the warm words. I'd appreciated it more if you could have just asterisked the expletitives and kept the jist of the post intact. Be that as it may, I'd sure welcome a meaningful reply. Live long etc.

Comment: Out of interest, are you seeing the screen as it was when the screen was locked, or its current contents?  A simple check would be to look at the clock in the top right corner.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that and it really doesn't matter, the point is that my data is here for everyone to see, stand by with a digicam and voilla! It doesn't happen every time and I really am in no mood to sit idle by the PC and test it, but it does happen frequently enough that this is a **major** security issue. I can't believe no one else is experiencing it, it happens on at least two Ubuntu 11.10 installs I'm using.

Comment: Well, it matters if we want to fix the problem.  If you are seeing an old version of the screen contents, it is probably related to the compositing code in Unity/Compiz.  If it is the current contents, that sounds more likely to be a problem with the screen saver.

Comment: just happened again. close to two seconds of unobstructed desktop view. clock displays the current time.

Comment: the rig is quadcore i5, 8 GB, SSD so I have no idea what takes two whole seconds.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).